# Django: declare key aliases into objects.filter function

Tags: python, django

I have a labelling problem that should be pretty easy but strangely I cannot find a way out to do that.

I have this filtering function

```
def search(cls, query):
    return cls.objects.filter(label__icontains=query)
```

And my model is just made up by a key and a label field. What I obtain looks like this

```
[{"id": 20, "label": "Title 1"}, {"id": 22, "label": "Title 2"}]
```

But I want just in my output use "name" instead of "label" and "key" instead of "id" alias, like this:

```
[{"key": 20, "name": "Title 1"}, {"key": 22, "name": "Title 2"}]
```

How can I declare these aliases directly into my filtering function without coding that elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of django's [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions.

```
def search(cls, query):
    qs = cls.objects.filter(label__icontains=query)
    return qs.annotate(key=F('id'), name=F('label')).values('key', 'name')
```

That way django will basically generate a query `SELECT id as key, label as name FROM ...`.

Comment: Wow, it works great! Thak you very much, you've made my day!